# Simplifying a polygon, result must contain original

Tags: polygon, nettopologysuite

I have some high-res polygons, without enclaves or exclaves that I want to simplify or smooth without loosing any part of the original.

Using `NettopologySuite` I could do `polygon.Buffer(x)` and then `DouglasPeuckerSimplifier` with `DistanceTolerance=x`

Perf doesn't matter since this is done during build.

Comment: Are you asking how to do this using some other software/library than NettopologySuite? If so, which?

Comment: Sorry, i realise that my question is not very clear.  I'm asking if Buffer+Simplify is the way to go. I have MSSQL, NettopologySuite and GDAL installed, and is willing to learn other tools if they are more suitable.